# Esri JS Api Zoom Out on MapView

Tags: javascript, zooming, esri

could you try to maximum zoom out with mouse please. as you can see viewdiv area shrink. Do you have any solution?

Here is the link

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/views-switch-2d-3d/index.html